# ¿Es posible declarar variables locales dentro de un lambda?

Tags: javascript, variables, lambda

Tengo una función *lambda (función flecha o anónima)* en *JavaScript*, la cual declara una variable, pero el problema es que la declara como una variable global, y yo quisiera que sea local (que solo sea accesible dentro del lambda).

```js
(x=>(
  a=2,
  console.log(a)
))()
console.log(a)
```

Si yo intento poner `var a = 2` dentro de la función, me tira error. ¿Es posible declararla localmente? y si es así, ¿Cómo implementarlo?

El primer `log`, debería dar `2`, y el segundo, tendría que dar error, porque no debería existir la variable de manera global, pero el problema es que siempre accede a la declarada dentro de la función.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saludos con el estandar ES6 tienes modos distintos de declarar el alcance de una variable, por ejemplo en tu ejercicio quieres que el primer console de 2 y el segundo error puesto que fuera del contexto de la arrow function no sabrá de la creación o existencia de dicha variable.

Usa el identificador **let** ya que con el declararás la variable solo al nivel del contexto donde se encuentra y fuera de el marcará que no existe:

**const** se parece en comportamiento a **let** pero a parte de que el valor debe ser declarado desde el inicio, su valor debe ser inmutable es decir te va a marcar error si después decides intencionalmente cambiarselo

Prueba con esto

```js
(x => {
      let a = 2
      console.log(a) //aquí dará 2
})()
 console.log(a) //aquí dará un error de que a is not defined que es lo que tu buscas suceda
```